# conformal map between the region of two circle intersect at one point and unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose that one circle is contained inside another and that they are tangent at the point $a$. Let $G$ be the region between the two circles. Show that you can map $G$ conformally onto the unit disk.

It seems that many solutions in google explain this first by applying a mobius transformation $z\mapsto \frac{1}{z-a}$ so that two circles maps to two parallel straight lines. Then apply rotation followed by translation, you can get any region bounded by two parallel lines. This is where I can't understand. Can you explain why it's true?

Comment: see as well [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1092058) or a particular case [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2803616).

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for your comment. But I'm not asking the answer of this question but rather, I'm wondering why 'rotation followed by translation' maps the region bounded by two parallel lines to any region bounded by two parallel lines